# injecting HTTP::Response objects in a WWW::Mechanize instance

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

what is the proper way of injecting an HTTP::Response (and implicitly or maybe explicitly as well the corresponding HTTP::Request) in a WWW::Mechanize instance, if any?

Basically I want to separate the downloading process so I can use PoCo::Client::HTTP, for example or AnyEvent::HTTP and use a $mech only to query the response and prepare further requests. And I need a way to grab the prepared HTTP::Request, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain [LWP::Protocol::AnyEvent::http](http://search.cpan.org/~ikegami/LWP-Protocol-AnyEvent-http-v1.0.5/lib/LWP/Protocol/AnyEvent/http.pm) will handle that for you.